# Regex to pick numeric quantities from a string but not years

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence that contains some quantities and the year in which they occur. I only want to extract said quantity. The quantity have commas or dots
Example: For `25,000 in 2015` I want only `25,000` extracted.

I am trying the regular expression:

`\d+[\d+.?,?\d+]+\d`

But it is picking 2015 as well. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the highest value you could expect?

Comment: try this `([0-9,]+)\b\s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *in year* part is mandatory:

```
\d+([,.]\d+)*(?= in \d{4})
```

Alternatively, you can use negative lookbehind for the *in*

```
(?<!in )\d+([,.]\d+)*
```

If the dots/commas are mandatory:

```
\d+([,.]\d+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this pattern

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*\b(?= in \d{4})
```

It expects that behind `" in ####"` will be the number you're looking for that will be in groups of 3 digits with separators between them.  If the number you're looking for is below 1,000 then it could just be 1 - 3 digits.

Tested @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iI7zT6/2)